# C++ Visual studios 2017 CHAR_MIN setting value to 0

Tags: c++, char, visual-studio-2017

I looked up the documentation to `CHAR_MIN` and I was wondering how do you set the `CHAR_MIN = 0`? When i look at the `limits.h` file its set to `SCHAR_MIN = -128`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx) Suggests setting the `/J`? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx) that recommends setting the /J option means for this to be a command line option.

You can Right Click on your project in Visual Studio > Properties > C/C++ > Command Line

Then at the bottom in "Additional Options" you can type /J

Note that [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned) has better instructions than the page you linked (more or less says what I typed above)

Comment: thank you I was looking for that page. Must have been an oversight the down vote was unnecessary. I am new to this.

Comment: Keep in mind that this makes `char` unsigned by default, which is what I assume you want because it does change CHAR_MIN as a side effect, but it may also change the behavior of your programs if you are not aware of it and don't write your code accordingly.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Good point, it could also cause some "interesting" behavior when interacting with libraries not compiled by OP

Comment: @AndyG We had some interesting problems back in the day when switching from Watcom with unsigned as default and Visual C++. :)

Comment: @k.wig If this answer solved you question, please mark it as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark under the downvote arrow for the answer